# Is intersection of a subset with a net a subnet?

Tags: general-topology, nets

Say $\{x_i\}_{i \in I}$ is a net in a set $X$ and $Y\subset X$ then, is $\{x_i\}_{i \in I}\cap Y$ a subnet? intuitively this seems true but I don't know how to approach the proof.

Comment: It is true if you impose the  condition: $x_{i_1} \in Y, x_{i_2} \in Y$ implies there exists $i \geq i_1, i_2$ such that $x_i \in Y$.

Comment: What do you mean by $\{x_i\}_{i\in I}\cap Y$?

Answer (score 1):

Be careful in your notations: the net is a fucntion $x: I \to X$ (often denoted for short by $\{x_i\}_{i \in I}$ and I can interpret your abuse of notation as

$x^{-1}[Y] = \{i \in I: x(i) \in Y\}$, and then you probably mean $x\restriction_{x^{-1}[Y]}$ as the subnet. It is indeed a map into $Y$, but for a net we need the domain to be directed. And for a subnet we need $x^{-1}[Y]$ to be cofinal in $I$, and then the directedness will follow from that of $I$:

So assume $x^{-1}[Y]$ is cofinal i.e.

$$\forall i \in I \exists j \in I: j \ge i \land x_j=x(j) \in Y$$

If this condition is satisfied then $x^{-1}[Y]$ is directed: if $i_1, i_2 \in x^{-1}[Y]$ we can find $i_3 \in I$ with $i_3 \ge i_1$ and $i_3 \ge i_2$, and then we have $i_4 \in x^{-1}[Y]$ so that $i_4 \ge i_3$ so by transitivity we have $i_4 \ge i_1,i_2$ as required. The inclusion map from $x^{-1}[Y]$ into $I$ shows then that $x\restriction_{x^{-1}[Y]}$ is indeed a subnet of $x$ (in both the Kelly and Willard sense, so in most texts, where one of these two is used as the definition of subnet..)

So yes iff $x^{-1}[Y]$ is cofinal in $I$.

Answer (score 0):

No. In order for something to be a subnet it has to:

1. Be a net. How exactly $\{x_i\}_{i\in I}\cap Y$ is a net? It is a set, not a map from a directed set. A natural choice would be to define $J=\{i\in I\ |\ x_i\in Y\}$ and $j\mapsto x_j$. But then we need that $J$ to be a directed set. I.e. it has to satisfy: if $x_i\in Y$ and $x_j\in Y$ then there exists $k\in I$ such that $k\geq i$, $k\geq j$ and $x_k\in Y$. With that your $\{x_i\}_{i\in I}\cap Y$ is indeed a net.
2. There is a final monotonic function $f:J\to I$, such that our net composed with $f$ is the subnet. In other words subnets arise only by modifying the directed domain via final monotonic functions.

With that we have a simple counterexample: assume that $Y$ is such that $\{x_i\}_{i\in I}\cap Y$ is a singleton, while $I$ is a directed poset with no maximal element (e.g. $I=\mathbb{N}$ and our net is actually a sequence). Then there is no final monotonic function $J\to I$ at all, and so the induced net $(x_j)_{j\in J}$ is not a subnet of $(x_i)_{i\in I}$

Comment: Strictly speaking, my point was that a preorder $I$ might have several elements $x$ such that $\forall y\in I, y\preceq x$, all of which must necessarily be related to one another (in this sense they form a complete graph), and that any sub-preorder containing one of those elements will be the domain of a subnet. I do see now (thanks for pointing out) that calling them "maximal" is inappropriate (I should have called them "graph of maxima" if anything) because directed sets may only have one maximal element (but several maxima).

Comment: @Gae.S. Isn't directed set a poset by definition?

Comment: I knew the definition with the index set being a preorder, but I guess that if you're dealing with nets in topological spaces you don't quite need the full generality of the preorder, because you should be able to factor through the poset of open sets.